# Having css property in variable in react hooks

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I need to remove some properties of html element and add some extra property based on some event.
I am trying to achieve this by creating one object variable for required css properties and trying to change it at runtime by assigning new object value to css variable.

Here is the sample code:

```
const MyCssVariableSample = (props) => {
  const [testCssVariable, setTestCssVariable] = useState({
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    color: "purple",
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setTestCssVariable({
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: "0",
            right: "0",
            color: "purple",
          }),
        }}
      >Hello there</button>
      <div className="xyz">
        <video id="abc" style={testCssVariable} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

but I am not able to do so as the code is allowing me to change the value of the defined keys but not introducing keys, so in this case, if I want to change height, width or color then it is fine, but I am not able to introduce position, margin or any other new keys.

This is the error:

> Argument of type '{ position: string; bottom: string; right: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ height: string; width: string; color: string; "background-color": string; position: string; bottom: string; right: string; }>'. Type '{ position: string; bottom: string; right: string; color: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ height: string; width: string; color: string; "background-color": string; position: string; bottom: string; right: string; }': height, width, "background-color"

How can I achieve the same? I am very new to react and hooks.

Comment: as someone already mentioned, the extra comma creates a syntax error, but otherwise this code works fine.

Comment: This is the error I am getting:
Argument of type '{ position: string; bottom: string; right: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ height: string; width: string; color: string; "background-color": string; position: string; bottom: string; right: string; }>'.
  Type '{ position: string; bottom: string; right: string; color: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ height: string; width: string; color: string; "background-color": string; position: string; bottom: string; right: string; }': height, width, "background-color"

Comment: This is a typescript problem, not a react problem. Try adding `as React.CSSProperties` after your declaration of the style objects: `const style = { position: 'absolute'} as React.CSSProperties`

Comment: Alternatively, just try running your code as vanilla js. It will work just fine then.

Comment: @M-N thanks, this helps! One question, I tried creating normal variable as React.CSSProperties and it worked as expected. But somehow, it is not working with variable I am initializing using hooks. I wonder, how this can be achieved with that!

  const remoteVideoTileStyle = {
    "background-color": "yellow",
    color: "yellow",
    display: "none",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
  } as React.CSSProperties; this worked.

But below didn't.

  const [localVideoTileStyle, setLocalVideoTileStyle] = useState({...}) as React.CSSProperties;

Comment: That's because `useState({...})` isn't a CSSProperties object. Only the `{...}` part is. The syntax would be `useState<React.CSSProperties>({...})`

Comment: @M-N I can't thank you enough!! This worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here,

```
        onClick={() => {
          setTestCssVariable({
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: "0",
            right: "0",
            color: "purple",
          }), // <- ','
        }}
```

Except that, Everything works and the position gets applied in my test, Check again after correcting the typo

Comment: Hi @ aXuser264, Thanks for your quick reply, but that is not typo, I have two such variables, while pasting code, I removed one to make question crisp and forgot to remove ",". Can you paste the code through which you tested if possible?

Comment: @tv1902 everything else look clean, i just removed that typo and everything worked, please give sandbox to find the problem quick !!

Comment: if it helps, this is the error:
Argument of type '{ position: string; bottom: string; right: string; color: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ height: string; width: string; color: string; "background-color": string; position: string; bottom: string; right: string; }>'.
  Type '{ position: string; bottom: string; right: string; color: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ height: string; width: string; color: string; "background-color": string; position: string; bottom: string; right: string; }': height, width, "background-color"

Comment: @tv1902 hey its all garbled up can you add it to the question

Comment: @tv1902 i cant catch anything from that example any live sandbox please ??